# Playing Freq Specific Tones in Ruby

Tags: ruby, macos, audio

What libraries/gems could I use to generate tones of a particular frequency/duration on a mac with Ruby?

Comment: Do you want to play them through the speakers, or create a file (e.g. WAV, MP3, OGG, etc.) with the sound information? Do you only want to generate on OS X, or also only need to play back there?

Comment: Ideally I'd like immediate playback through the speakers when the script is run.  As well as the option to output files.  This only needs to occur on a mac for now.  I used to do something similar in MATLAB on a windows machine.